# Acessing elements in XML that are in a namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

Providing a namespace prefix in order to transform XML to XSLT has been broadly covered at SO. See e.g. [XSLT Transform XML with Namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1730947/2657875), [XSLT with XML source that has a default namespace set to xmlns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1344192/2657875), and [XSLT Transformating XML to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42093251/2657875). However, after countless hours of research and trial-and-error approach I can say that I failed to make it work.

Here's my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<library xmlns="http://void.net/library/1.0">
    <catalog>
        <cd id="c1">
            <singer id="s1">
                <name>Kate</name>
                <surname>Apple</surname>
            </singer>
        <title>Great CD</title>
        </cd>
        <cd id="c2">
            <singer id="s2">
                <name>Mary</name>
                <surname>Orange</surname>
            </singer>
        <title>Even better CD</title>
        </cd>
    </catalog>
</library>
```

This is what I've come up so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    xmlns:b="http://void.net/library/1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="b">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />

    <xsl:template match="/b:library">
        <xsl:text>singer,title
        </xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="b:catalog/b:cd">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(b:singer/b:name, ' ', b:singer/b:surname, ', ', b:title, '
')" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's [example and error list](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/?save=044562e9-045c-45d5-98b4-6e3d3cce7e8c-xsltransformation)

Comment: What's does not work?

Comment: @zx485 Please see my updated post for errorlist.

Comment: There is a syntax error in the stylesheet. Remove the right angle bracket immediately after "Transform".

Comment: This question should be closed because it was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the typos in the stylesheet and came up with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:b="http://void.net/library/1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="b">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />

    <xsl:template match="/b:library">
        <xsl:text>singer,title&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="b:catalog/b:cd">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(b:singer/b:name, ' ', b:singer/b:surname, ', ', b:title, '&#xa;')" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
singer,title
Kate Apple, Great CD
Mary Orange, Even better CD
```

So everything seems to work as expected.